# How to implement the following time-selection as part of a scheduling component?

Tags: html, angular, angular7

I have the following sketch that generates a schedule matrix (y-axis time steps and x-axis dates):

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr class="header">
    <th></th>
    <th *ngFor="let day of weekDays">
      <small *ngIf="day.isToday">Today</small>
      <br/> {{day.title}}
    </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="this.schedule !== undefined">
  <tr *ngFor="let time of this.schedule.commonTimes">
    <td class="common-time">{{time}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let day of weekDays">
      <div class="appointment-time" (click)="selectAppointmentTime(this.schedule.groupedDayTimes[day.code][time])"
           *ngIf="this.schedule.groupedDayTimes[day.code] !== undefined && this.schedule.groupedDayTimes[day.code][time] !== undefined">
              <span>
                  {{this.schedule.groupedDayTimes[day.code][time].dateTime.format('hh:mm A')}}
              </span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and it produces the following output:

[image]

However, it isn't very good UX-wise because `timeStep` values of 15m requires to scroll down with a lot of entries.

Therefore I'd like to have something more like the following sketch, where basically the y-axis outlines the start of each hour and the day column accommodates multiple time slots within:
[image]

What `HTML` structure would be best to achieve this floating multi-column approach? Any suggestions how to make it mobile friendly too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question brought Masonry to my mind, which I used a long time ago for something like this. https://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html

The Masonry FAQ brought me to Packery, which supports draggable interaction. https://packery.metafizzy.co/

Then there is also Isotope, which also has some info about all three packages: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/faq.html#difference-between-isotope-masonry-and-packery